# Unknown exported text artifacts $FL? $G?

Tags: character-encoding

I have received a flat file to import in a DB. This flat file has many problems: the French text characters are converted to ? (it is not my editor, the file as realy the "3F" = "?" ASCII character for different letters with accent. But the main problem is that this file is studded with strange artefacts: "$FL?", "$B?", "$E?". They are anywhere, including in the middle of words.
It does not seams to be quotted printable.

Have you already faced such symptoms and what was the cause ?

Comment: Are you sure the file is a text file, meant to be readable like that?

Comment: It's a flat file delimited by semi-coma just generated for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theses artifacts are created by an upstream buggy program and are not related to encoding changes.